# Is |AxBxC| = |Ax(BxC)|?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Is the cardinality of AxBxC different to that of Ax(BxC), since AxBxC gives a 3 tuple, but Ax(BxC) gives a two tuple? but in such case, what would be the formula for calculating the cardinality of Ax(BxC) ? since in the sets A = {1,2}   B = {3,4}   C={5,6}   |AxBxC| = 2*2*2 = 8, but |Ax(BxC)| would be 2*(2*2) = 2*(4) = also 8...

Comment: Is there a bijection between the two sets? (Yes.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an obvious bijection between the sets $A \times B \times C$ and $A \times (B \times C)$:
$$f(a,b,c) = (a, (b,c))$$
For $a \in A$, $b \in B$, and $c \in C$.

Once you've checked that this is a bijection, then you'll see the sets have the same cardinality.